# Scriptlab throwing a "'$' is undefined" error in Excel and Word

Tags: office-js, scriptlab

Trying to run the samples in [Scriptlab](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/garage/profiles/script-lab/), and getting the classic "'$' is undefined" javascript error. This usually indicates a loading/URL problem, but any ideas on how to deal with that in Scriptlab?

steps: 
1) download scriptlab from https://aka.ms/getscriptlab 
2) env is windows 10 with office 365 proplus subscription (deferred channel)
3) try to run the basic API sample

The full error is:

```
description: "'$' is undefined" 
number: -2146823279 
stack :
"ReferenceError: '$' is undefined\n   at Office.initialize (https://script-lab-runner.azureedge.net/compile/page:92:13)\n   at window.scriptRunnerEndInit (https://script-lab.azureedge.net/bundles/runner.aa0d3ff3e68d9a8b0d5d.bundle.js:1:399327)\n   at Global code (https://script-lab-runner.azureedge.net/compile/page:146:9)"
```

The sample is expected to color the currently selected range yellow, but fails with the above error.

--
EDIT: Turns out, this was caused by content filtering in our firewall. Changing the content filtering categories (switching it off/excluding Microsoft sites from filtering) fixed the issue, and now this works. no changes to the addin/scriptlab needed.

Comment: Can try running in Excel online to see if it works there (to rule out network issues)

Comment: thx Sudhi. Tried Excel Online - but still getting an error - 
["'$' is undefined", "https://script-lab-runner.azureedge.net/compile/page", 92, 13, ReferenceError: '$' is undefined {}].
Is there any setting/path that I should be checking on my account?